# System.Threading.Timer not firing

Tags: multithreading, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, background-process

I'm writing an app that will send location data every x seconds, and run in the background. I'm calling the following method.

```
    public void StartListening()
    {
        UpdateGpsService();
        if(CLLocationManager.LocationServicesEnabled)
        {
            locationManager.DesiredAccuracy = 10;

            nint taskId = UIApplication.SharedApplication.BeginBackgroundTask(() =>
           {
               timer = new Timer((o) =>
               {
                   CLLocation location = locationManager.Location;
                   Nmea nmea = new IOSNmea(location);
                   Gprmc gprmc = new Gprmc();
                   gprmc.url = this.Url;
                   gprmc.Id = this.DeviceId;
                   gprmc.GprmcString = nmea.ToString();

               }, null, 0, UpdateInterval * 1000);
           });

            App.Database.SaveItemAsync(new TodoItem() { key = LOCATOR_SERVICE_ID, value = taskId.ToString() });
        }
    }
```

However, it doesn't seem to be calling the code inside the timer callback. I tried putting a breakpoint in there, and it never gets called. Is there something obviously wrong with my code? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

`BeginBackgroundTask` only tells iOS that you are starting a long running task and the handler is *not* for the execution of that task, BUT it is a *completion handler* that is called when the OS is about to shut it down...

```
Timer timer = null;
nint taskId = UIApplication.SharedApplication.BeginBackgroundTask(() =>
{
    // Clean up as the background task is begin shutdown by iOS
    timer?.Dispose();
});
timer = new Timer((o) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Timer Update");
}, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

// Must call EndBackgroundTask when you are done with this...
// UIApplication.SharedApplication.EndBackgroundTask(taskId);
```

Comment: So is the code between the BeginBackgroundTask and EndBackgroundTask the code that gets executed? If so, how would I kill the background task manually if that needs to be done.

Comment: @user2850818 *Typically* you would do this in a new non-UI thread (either instance a Thread or Task.Run) as you can actually have multiple iOS "Tasks" that have been flagged as background tasks. The code that is within that "task" is anything on that thread between the Begin and End Background task calls... this is used to notified the OS that once iOS places the app in the background, you have one or more tasks that need to be completed before the OS terminates them and thus iOS starts its own timer before the termination happens, which you call monitor via the BackgroundTimeRemaining propert